# Firebase - Transaction load all data

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

I notice something in my firebase transaction. I would like to know if there is something to do about it.

To explain my issue, I did a small test. I have this data in my realtime database

```
test
    nbElement : 4
    list
        "1" : value1
        "2" : value2
        "3" : value3
        "4" : value4
```

In other words, I have an array of string and a counter. I want to increase the counter each time I add a value in the array. The user will often add a value in the array and the array can be "big". The user will check often the nbElement in the array but the user rarely read every element of the array.

I did this transaction.

```
m_databaseRef.child("test")
    .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

            //increase nb element
            MutableData nbElementMD = mutableData.child("nbElement");
            Long nbElement = (Long) nbElementMD.getValue();
            if(nbElement == null){
                nbElement = 0L;
            }

            ++nbElement;
            nbElementMD.setValue(nbElement);

            //add element
            MutableData listMD = mutableData.child("list");
            MutableData element = listMD.child(nbElement.toString());
            element.setValue("Value" + nbElement.toString());

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
        }
    });
```

It's working fine. When I call the function the "nbElements" increase properly and the new element is added to the array. But there is an issue. If a put a breakpoint at the beginning of the transation and I ran the transaction. I can see the variable "MutableData mutableData" in the watch window. the result look like this.

```
MutableData { key = <none>, value = {list={3=Value3, 2=Value2, 1=Value1, 4=Value4}, nbElement=4} }
```

Then, every elements of the array can be seens in the client application at the begginning of the transation. That mean, the client received every element from the internet. I do not want to receive every element of the array, I just want to increase one data and add an element in the array. If the array is big, the data transfered from the network will be huge for no reason. There is a way to avoid receiving all the data in "test" and change only the data I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look like this is the expected behavior. I had to do a "hack" to avoid sending all the list to the client. The client will resend all the data to the server too. Then if you have an array of 100 elements and you want to add one in a transaction, every element will be sent to the client and the client will resend all 100 +1 element to server...

But it look like a new feature in firebase will answer my pray

Firebase function! I don't know when the feature won't be in "beta" anymore, but I will take a look for this

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/